# Synchronice folder in java. so which jar is required for it

Tags: java, dropbox, data-synchronization

I have to make app using java technology and it should work same as drop box is working. So can you suggest how to start or which jar is required for it?

Answer (score 1):

From the question it looks like you are new to Java. So your best bet would be to use an existing library to do the sync. Java is often not considered the ideal choice for file intensive tasks due to performance issues.

eg:
http://jfilesync.sourceforge.net/

Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283958/java-folder-synchronisation-class-library